# Is this a redux middleware anti-pattern? How to properly build async actions with middleware

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

Just built my first API Middleware and was just wondering where I'm suppose to chain promises for action creators that dispatch multiple actions.  Is what I did an anti-pattern:

```
export const fetchChuck = () => {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      types: [ CHUCK_REQUEST, CHUCK_SUCCESS, CHUCK_FAILURE ],
      endpoint: `jokes/random`
    }
  }
}

export const saveJoke = (joke) => {
  return { type: SAVE_JOKE, joke: joke }
}

export const fetchAndSaveJoke = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchChuck()).then((response) => {
      dispatch(saveJoke(response.response.value.joke))
    })
  }
}
```

Should fetchAndSaveJoke dispatch the section action in my react component or is it okay to have it as its own action creator?

Comment: What's the "section action"?  Also, you should post your middleware code, otherwise the example isn't really self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that at this point in the Redux world, it's not super clear what's best practice and what the anti-patterns are. It's a very unopinionated tool. While that's been great for a diverse ecosystem to flourish, it does present challenges for people looking for ways to organize their apps without running into pitfalls or excessive boilerplate. From what I can tell, your approach seems to be roughly in line with the advice from the Redux guide. The one thing that looks funny to me is that it seems like `CHUCK_SUCCESS` should probably make `SAVE_JOKE` unnecessary.

I personally find it rather awkward to have action creators dispatch more actions, and so I worked out the approach behind [react-redux-controller](https://github.com/artsy/react-redux-controller). It's brand new, so it's certainly not a "best practice", but I'll throw it out there in case you or someone else wants to give it a try. In that workflow, you'd have a controller method that looks something like:

```
// actions/index.js

export const CHUCK_REQUEST = 'CHUCK_REQUEST';
export const CHUCK_SUCCESS = 'CHUCK_SUCCESS';
export const CHUCK_FAILURE = 'CHUCK_FAILURE';

export const chuckRequest = () => { type: CHUCK_REQUEST };
export const chuckSuccess = (joke) => { type: CHUCK_SUCCESS, joke };
export const chuckFailure = (err) => { type: CHUCK_FAILURE, err };

// controllers/index.js
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'; // or whatever
import * as actions from '../actions';

const controllerGenerators = {
  // ... other controller methods
  *fetchAndSaveJoke() {
    const { dispatch } = yield getProps;

    // Trigger a reducer to set a loading state in your store, which the UI can key off of
    dispatch(actions.chuckRequest());

    try {
      const response = yield fetch('jokes/random');
      dispatch(actions.chuckSuccess(response.response.value.joke));
    } catch(err) {
      dispatch(actions.chuckFailure(err));
    }
  },
};
```